# How do I return an array of objects using `impl Trait` from a function without boxing?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a Sudoku crate, and I'd like to allow the possibility of higher-dimension Sudokus. In 2 dimensions, there are 3 groups that need to be checked for correctness (the prime rule contains only 3 subrules) and position (by definition) requires only 2 coordinates to fully specify, but in higher dimensions this obviously increases.

I wrote the following method signature, but it doesn't work, and I'd like to avoid boxing at all costs due to the environments for which I'm developing.

```
pub fn groups(position: [u8; DIMENSIONS]) -> [impl Group; DIMENSIONS + 1]
```

The actual type of each group will be known at compile time (the actual type will be something like `[Box, Stack, Band]`), but it appears that the compiler doesn't like this even though it'll know the size of each element.

I'd love to be able to use a tuple with size determined at compile time, but that doesn't seem to be easily supported, unless I'm missing something.

---

The idea is that there are [three types of `Group`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Sudoku#Terminology_and_grid_layout): a `Stack` (column), a `Band` (row), and a `Box`. The definition for `Group` is given below.

```
pub trait Group {
    /// A group is considered valid if it has contains only unique elements.
    fn is_valid(&self) -> bool { /* Default implementation elided. */ }
    /// Returns an owned copy of the group's constituent elements.
    fn elements(&self) -> Vec<Option<Element>>;
}
```

Let's start with the two-dimensional case. For a given element, we can write the element's index as a double (i.e. 2-tuple) `(x, y)`. The groups associated with this element are then one `Box` (as always; this is where `DIMENSION + 1` comes from), one `Stack`, and one `Band`.

In three dimensions, a given element is indexed (by definition) by a triple (i.e. 3-tuple) `(x, y, z)`. The groups associated with this element are then one `Box`, one `Stack`, and *two* `Band`s.

This trend continues into higher dimensions, and I want to enable the user to use a different dimensionality — thus the compile-time determination of sizes.

To check the puzzle for correctness, the caller simply calls `Group::is_valid()` on each of `puzzle.groups()`; they can also iterate over each to render the puzzle as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because all `impl Trait` guarantees is that it's some type that implements `Trait`. Arrays in Rust are homogeneous, each element must be the same type, but something like `[impl Group; DIMENSIONS + 1]` would mean that each element could be any type as long as it implemented `Group`.

It's difficult to say without more code but this could probably be accomplished by parameterizing on the type of `Group`:

```
pub fn groups<T: Group>(position: [u8; DIMENSIONS]) -> [T; DIMENSIONS + 1]
```

Now there will be one instance of the `groups()` function monomorphized for each kind of `T` it's called with which implements `Group`. This has the consequence that the returned array is fixed to that type only, allowing it to be homogeneous. Since the function has no parameter of type `T`, the type of `T` probably can't be inferred unless it can be inferred from the call-site (e.g. `let x: [SomeGroup; 3] = groups([...])`), so you would need to explicitly specify the type with `groups::<SomeGroup>([...])`.

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but it communicates the general idea that you need to set the array to some fixed type. That is, `[T; N]` is fixed to `T` whereas `[impl Trait; N]` would imply that each element can be *any* type that implements `Trait`, which itself would imply that it's a heterogeneous array, but arrays in Rust are homogeneous.

I can't tell if you also want to parameterize on the constant `DIMENSIONS`, which requires [RFC 2000: const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2000-const-generics.md) which AFAIK isn't implemented yet, even in nightly. You probably don't need that if you're able to infer it from the parameter, as you seem to be doing.

```
pub fn groups<T: Group, const DIMENSIONS: usize>(position: [u8; DIMENSIONS])
  -> [T; DIMENSIONS + 1]
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of — I suspected there wasn't a way to make a heterogeneous array, but I was hoping there was something. Is there another way to notate "I'm going to give you an ordered set of exactly *n* values that all implement this trait?" I'm not opposed to using something like a procedural macro generating an *n*-tuple, either, if that's the way I have to do this.

Comment: There may be something that can be done, and I'm happy to help, but I honestly have trouble visualizing what exactly you're trying to do. Would you be kind enough to add some more context such as some types and some examples of the different ways in which the function may be called? It doesn't have to compile, though that'd help too.

Comment: Otherwise, as a guess, one traditional way this can be done, but again I'm lacking context so this may be off in your case, is to create an enumeration so you have `enum Group { Box, Stack, Band }`, then since each variant is still the same type, you can store each one in the same array: `[Group::Box, Group::Stack, Group::Band]`. You can add additional data directly within a variant if necessary by using an enum struct variant, e.g. `enum Group { Box { size: u8, name: String }, ... }`

Comment: If you don't want to store data directly within a variant in the form of a struct variant, you can also create a separate struct that is embedded within the variant, e.g. `struct Box { ... }`, `enum Group { Box(Box), ... }`. It's essentially the same but has different ergonomics, in this case you can easily move the contained `Box` to pass to something else once you take it out of the enum variant.

Comment: I suppose, since I know that there will only ever be three variants, that I could drop the trait altogether and go with an enum instead. However, since variants will be different sizes (unless padding happens automatically?), do I not still have the same issue?

Comment: Good question, nope. Think of an enum as a tagged C union, so each variant takes up the same size (more or less the max size of any variant, give or take padding/alignment). Depending on your situation, you can probably minimize this by storing references to the structs instead of the data itself. Also, if you still need the trait for whatever reason, you can still implement it for the enum as a whole, just that the array now contains the enum type.